# How to put y axis of line chart to right when combined with bar chart in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a graph where I am trying to draw a pareto chart by using chart.js. I am combining bar chart and line chart to achieve this. Here is my sample graph:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
       this.chartData = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: lineData,
                label: "Cumulative Total of Number of Reassignments",
                type: 'line',
                fill: false,
                datalabels: {
                  color: "#0f0f0f"
                },
              },
              {
                label: "Number of Reassignments",
                data: datasetsLabel,
                datalabels: {
                  color: "#0f0f0f"
                }
              },
            ]
          }
```

lineData array holds the values 45.87, 64.22, etc.
datasetsLabel array holds the values 250, 100, 90, etc.

I tried to use the following options:

```
      this.options = {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    stepSize: 5,
                  },
                },
                {
                  display: true,
                  position: 'right',
                  ticks: {
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    stepSize: 10
                  }
                }
              ],
            },
          }
```

What I want to achieve is put 45.87, 62.22, etc values to the right side of the graph. How can I achieve this?